# Cleaning up typo tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-cleanup

**Disclaimer: I am relatively new to this site and Stack Exchange *Tags* in general.**

I recently passed the reputation barrier for creating new tags and though to myself, "Hey, that's pretty cool, I can make whatever tags I want for my post to make it more findable."

But I also recently came across a side effect of allowing users to create tags that just automatically show up for everyone else:

[image]

Notice the two misspellings of *amplifier* in tags next to the correct *operational-amplifier* tag.

One of these faux tags was only used by one user in one post, but the other tripped up three different users.

I would love to be able to click delete on both of those (and other tags that have typos or are best merged into existing ones) and have all the posts that use them automatically updated. It would be a pain to go through editing them all manually.

What can be done with bad tags on EE short of editing them out of a post? If no adequate solution already exists, how difficult would it be to make a system where new tags are sent to random moderators to sniff over, and remove and swap out in the case of typos or lack of concision? Vetting tags seems like a good way to clear up some clutter on EE.

Answer (score 3):

Edit every question with the incorrect tag by removing the incorrect tag and replacing it with the tag with correct spelling.

> There is a script that runs daily to hide (soft-delete) tags that don't have any associated questions.

See: [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it/71124#71124)